# How to preserve header as a column and have an index after transposing dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with headers X,Y,Z which looks like this -

```
   0 X Y Z
   0 P P P
   1 P P P
   2 P P P
```

I have a 0 in the header because I changed the header row from the default unnamed row in my excel file. My header before  was `Unnamed: 1  Unnamed:2...Unnamed: 34` I changed the header row like this -

```
    header_row = df_1.iloc[0]
    df_1 = df_1[1:]
    df_1.columns = header_row
```

When I transpose it, it looks like -

```
   0 0 1 2
   X P P P
   Y P P P
   Z P P P
```

Instead of the headers (X,Y.Z) becoming index, how can I add it as a new column in the data frame so that it looks like this ?

```
    0 1 2 3
  0 X P P P
  1 Y P P P
  2 Z P P P
```

I have tried `df.T.reset_index()`. It gives me the error - `ValueError: cannot insert 0, already exists`.

Comment: Please provide the dataframe constructor. We don't know where is index or column header. `print(df.to_dict())`

Comment: The headers X,Y,Z are actually dates. I got - {datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 31, 0, 0): {0: 'P', 1: 'P', 2: 'P', 3: 'P', 4: 'P', 5:......  236: 'P', 237: nan}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead your solution try first transpose and then remove `Unnamed`  index values - set to default values:

```
df_1 = pd.read_csv(file)
print (df_1)
  Unnamed 1 Unnamed 4  Unnamed 7
0         X         Y          Z
1         P         P          P
2         P         P          P
3         P         P          P


df_1 = df_1.T.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df_1)
   0  1  2  3
0  X  P  P  P
1  Y  P  P  P
2  Z  P  P  P
```